# svg renders differently in browser and imagemagick (using rsvg convert)

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, rsvg

I am using **imagemagick** with **rsvg-convert** to **convert svgs into jpegs**. Everything works fine except when **using gamma function to color correct images**. It produces very different image than the one in browser.

Here is a preview of what the svg looks like in the browser.
[image: Preview in chrome/firefox]

This is the output of imagemagick+rsvg-convert after compiling the same svg
[image: Converted image]

See how the details are blown out in the output image. Here is a link to download the [actual svg with images](http://ec2-52-19-237-240.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/13.zip)

I tested it on windows as well as on ubuntu and centos using the same version below (see the picture for IM version).
[image]

Here are a couple commands i tried so far. Every command outputs the same blown out image.

- convert test.svg test.jpg
- Applied im evaluate function to single image - convert green_1186.jpg -evaluate pow 1 -evaluate multiply 1.54 -evaluate add 0 green_1186.c.jpg (produces blown out image)
- Applied gamma to the image - convert green_1186.jpg -gamma 1,1.54,0  green_1186.c.jpg
- convert green_1186.jpg -colorspace srgb -evaluate pow 1 -evaluate multiply 1.54 -evaluate add 0 green_1186.c.jpg
- convert green_1186.jpg -fx "1.54*(pow(u,1))+0" green_1186.c.jpg
- convert green_1186.jpg -auto-gamma -fx "1.54*(pow(u,1))+0" green_1186.c.jpg

I am not sure if the svg is wrong or i need to re-sample the values for IM or if the commands are wrong. I would really appreciate an expert thought on this matter.

Comment: What version of RSVG and what version of Imagemagick. Try installing Inkscape and Imagemagick will use it. It might work better than RSVG.

Comment: Imagemagick 6.9.10.24 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra gives error messages when trying to read your SVG file with Imagemagick internal MSVG renderer and with Inkscape. So I suspect something is corrupt in your file or at least not according to specs. There are linked files which cannot be found.

Comment: Please post a minimal verifiable test file ...